# Minikube tunnel keeps asking for sudo

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, tunnel

When I use `minikube tunnel` I have the problem that it keeps asking me for the sudo password.

It reask's for the password each ~5s. 
If I dont type in my password it exits with an error. How can I avoid the repetitive password-question?

The following log shows my problem (first entering the password --> no errors, after 5 seconds I don't enter any password --> error)

```
minikube tunnel
[sudo] Password for user: 
Status:
        machine: minikube
        pid: 31390
        route: 10.96.0.0/12 -> 192.168.39.82
        minikube: Running
        services: []
    errors: 
                minikube: no errors
                router: no errors
                loadbalancer emulator: no errors
Status:
        machine: minikube
        pid: 31390
        route: 10.96.0.0/12 -> 192.168.39.82
        minikube: Unknown
        services: []
    errors: 
                minikube: error getting host status for minikube: getting connection: getting domain: error connecting to libvirt socket.: virError(Code=45, Domain=60, Message='Authentifikation gescheitert: access denied by policy')
                router: no errors
                loadbalancer emulator: no errors
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was, that my user wasnt in the `libvirt` group anymore. I found out by following command:
`sudo getent group | grep libvirt`

After readding myself (using arch) to the libvirt group:

`sudo gpasswd -a MYUSER libvirt`

And relogin, everything works.

Comment: Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: my user is in the `libvirt` group but i still get sudo errors. perhaps because my minikube driver is `virtualbox`.